# How to fix "Type '{ key: number; }' is missing the following properties" when sending props with spread operator in Next.js App directory?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to upgrade a Next.js v.13 `/pages` directory project to `/app` directory. Both projects are using the latest packages and I'm doing exactly what I've done in the other project, but for some reason I'm getting an error when sending props in a map loop in the `/app` directory project.

I'm using generated types using Supabase CLI.

components/card.tsx

```
// types from products table row
        Row: {
          category_id: number | null
          description: string | null
          featured_in: number | null
          id: number
          name: string | null
          preview: string | null
          price: number | null
          sale: boolean | null
          sale_price: number | null
          sale_text: string | null
          stock: number | null
        }

// no errror in this page
export default function OverviewCard(props: Product): JSX.Element {}
```

components/products.tsx

```
  'use client'

  export default function OverviewProducts(): JSX.Element {
    // products fetched using @tanstack/react-query

    return (
      <div className='items-grid'>
        {products && (
          <>
            {products
              .map((produkt, i) => (
                <OverviewCard key={i} {...produkt} />
                // ☝️ I'm getting the error here
              ))}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    )
```

I'm getting this error which I don't have in the other project and I've done the exact same expect I'm using `/app` directory.

> Type '{ key: number; }' is missing the following properties from type
> '{ category_id: number | null; description: string | null;
> featured_in: number | null; id: number; name: string | null; preview:
> string | null; price: number | null; sale: boolean | null; sale_price:
> number | null; sale_text: string | null; stock: number | null; }':
> category_id, description, featured_in, id, and 7 more.

Also if click on the hover helper button in VSCode `Quick Fix... (Ctrl+.)` it adds all the "missing attributes" which is just all the values in `Product` type.

What am I doing wrong in the code or did I miss something about the new `/app` directory?

Comment: What is the type of `products` (the result from react-query)?

Comment: @vr. It's an object array. https://i.gyazo.com/a421cd217b550227866c7f8aca1c10cb.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment we can see that the `products` **value** is an array of objects with fields that you need. However, since the error you have is from typescript, typescript doesn't know about what is the **type** of the data that you just fetched. If you hover over `products` in VSCode it will likely say `any`. To fix your issue you can either provide type for it or type cast it in the part of the code that you omitted from your question in

```
// products fetched using @tanstack/react-query
```